# Find the Position of a Four Digit Number in Text String. (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

20/11/2022  12:00:52   2  X  15.95  15.95  USD  57   5   689  5  689  1        4111   0   Amazing Lego Team

I need to get the position of No 4111 in the above text string, As an excel beginner any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

All of the Text Strings will have a 4 digit number like 4111 which i have to get the position for.

Have tried using this formula to get four digit number in another column, LOOKUP(10^15,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),5)+0) but I am looking to get position instead.

I have tried using lookup but I could only go so far as a beginner.

Comment: this would be easier with Google Sheets regular expression function if that is an option

Comment: @Slai my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Unfortunately NO, No google sheets are allowed in my office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula you provided `=LOOKUP(10^15,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),5)+0)` to identify the number, and use `FIND` to get the position of the number.

```
Cell A1="20/11/2022 12:00:52 2 X 15.95 15.95 USD 57 5 689 5 689 1 4111 0 Amazing Lego Team"

=FIND(LOOKUP(10^15,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),5)+0),A1)
=58
```

Comment: My friend, the 4 digit number is going to be dynamic. so this wont work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be in a space (or some other character) delimited text string. If you have a bunch of rows of data like this, use the Text to Columns feature on the Data tab. Use the Delimited option and then click the check box next to space (or other if it's something custom not in the available options) and Excel will split the data into columns for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your string example, if you know that your 4 digit is started 58 char from the beginning of the string, use `=MID(A1,58,4)` A1 is the cell with your string.

[MID function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-function-2eba57be-0c05-4bdc-bf81-5ecf4421eb8a) returns a specific number of characters from a text string, starting at the position you specify, based on the number of characters you specify.

Comment: Thanks, But It will be random, since price in the field and other number might have different value., I just want to get the position so I can extract (Amazing Lego Team) from there, =right wouldn't work for that since it will have a different value in each cell.

Comment: Are you able to explain to us the logic for identifying the 4 digits you want to extract?

Comment: There is only one four digit number in the entire string. That doesn't have text attached to it, For example you can see a 4 digit no as 2022 in date as well but it has "/" in front of it, But the no 4111 in this example is will not have anything except may be a space in beginning or the end of it. Does it make sense?

Comment: I found this formula online that extracts the 4 digit no. =LOOKUP(10^15,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),5)+0) but i need the position not the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1,," "),
FIND(FILTER(t,(LEN(t)=4)*(ISNUMBER(--(t)))),A1))
```

It splits the string at every space and filters the result for being of length of 4 characters and not being an error if converted to number.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to get the position of that no. Do you happen to know how to achieve that?

Comment: Wrap it in find